# Kaffeine tv soft

Tags: delete

I installed *Kaffeine tv* software for television support.

I don't need it any longer.
I couldn't find it in "intalled softwares"

What should I do in order to remove it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt remove kaffeine
```